# how to cast up to super class when there is an override function in the sub class

Tags: swift, class, types, casting

A super-class **Car** and a sub-class **Jaguar** was created. The function ***info() -> Void*** in the sub-class overrided the super-class' function. A instance named **theAuto** of type **Jaguar** had been created.

**Problem:**

Seems I cannot up casts the **theAuto** to the type of **Car**, please see the code snippet and its comments

```
class Car {
        func info() {
                print("You've got a car")
        }
}

class Jaguar : Car {
       override func info() {
               print("You've got a Jaguar")
       }
}

let theAuto = Jaguar()
theAuto.info() // --> You've got a Jaguar
let auto = theAuto as Car // casting but seems not working 
auto.info() // --> You've got a Jaguar
print(type(of: auto)) // fail to casting
```

**Question:**

I think I didn't fully understand the concept of casting together with override scenario. Why I cannot make the up casting? Is the override action limited my upper casting?

many thanks for your help and time

Comment: You must have to create the Car instance if you want to call info method of Car class. it will only call in that case if you don't override the info method. if you override any method from it's super class then it always call the sub class method.

Comment: @Sahil I changed the line to "let auto:Car = Jaguar()"  from "let Car = Jaguar()" but it doesn't working

Comment: You can create the object of base class by using the instance of its super class, so the object can point the every member of itself and its super class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're *overriding* the method in a subclass, you're getting *dynamic* dispatch. The method implementation to call will be based on the dynamic type of the instance that it's called on. Upcasting a `Jaguar` to a `Car` only changes the *static* type of the instance – the dynamic type is still a `Jaguar`, for that's the type of instance you created.

Therefore upcasting has no bearing whatsoever on the dynamic dispatch of a method – nor should it, as the whole point of dynamic dispatch is to ensure that the correct method implementation for the given instance is called *no matter* what it's statically typed as.

The kind of behaviour you're expecting is *static* dispatch – the compiler chooses the implementation to call based on the static type of the instance. This is commonly achieved by *overloading* (rather than overriding) functions.

For example, an overloaded `static` method:

```
class Car {
    static func info(for car: Car) {
        print("You've got a Car")
    }
}

class Jaguar : Car {
    static func info(for jaguar: Jaguar) {
        print("You've got a Jaguar")
    }
}

let jaguar = Jaguar()
Jaguar.info(for: jaguar) // You've got a Jaguar
Car.info(for: jaguar)    // You've got a Car

let car = jaguar as Car
Jaguar.info(for: car)    // You've got a Car
```

Here, the compiler resolves which implementation of `info(for:)` to call based on the static types of what it's being called on and the arguments being passed. If it's either called on `Car`, or the argument passed is statically typed as a `Car`, only `Car`'s overload can possibly be statically dispatched to.

Another example of static dispatch is with a protocol extension, where the method isn't a protocol requirement (as making it a requirement gives it dynamic dispatch).

```
protocol Car {}

extension Car {
    func info() {
        print("You've got a Car")
    }
}

class Jaguar : Car {
    func info() {
        print("You've got a Jaguar")
    }
}

let jaguar = Jaguar()
jaguar.info() // You've got a Jaguar

let car = jaguar as Car
car.info()    // You've got a Car
```

Here, the compiler resolves which implementation of `info()` to call solely based on the static type of the instance that it's called on.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help

Comment: Happy to help @SLN :)

Answer (score 1):

`theAuto` is always a `Jaguar`. It is also always a `Car`. However, calling `info()` will always return the implementation for the most specific type and so will always print

> You've got a Jaguar

---

Regarding casting:

```
let car1 : Car = Jaguar()
let car2 : Car = BMW()

if let automobile = car1 as? Jaguar {
    print ("The automobile is a Jaguar")
    car1.info()
}

if let automobile = car2 as? Jaguar {
    print ("The automobile is a Jaguar")
    car2.info()
}
```

prints

> The automobile is a Jaguar
>   You've got a Jaguar

Only the first section prints. The second car cannot be cast to a Jaguar, because it is a BMW.

Comment: then its but natural, car2 is a instance of Car and object of BMW so it wont responds to Jaguar.