# casting from child to parent retains overrides in debug but not production when using generics?

Tags: ios, swift

I've run into an issue with a generic implementation I've been working on for UITableView cells. I managed to reproduce the same issue with the below example code.

The problem is that in production builds, the base classes `bind` function is called instead of the child classes `bind` function. The part of this that is the most confusing me is that this issue only comes up when I build my application for `production` yet when I build the application for `debug`, it works just fine.

```swift
func viewDidLoad(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad(animated)

    let vm = CustomCellViewModel()
    vm.asUITableViewCell(viewController: self)
}

// this class replaces UITableViewCell for the purposes of this minimum test case.
class unrelated {
    static func unrelatedCustomCell() -> unrelated {
        return CustomCell()
    }
}

class CellViewModel: NSObject {
    func asUITableViewCell(viewController: ViewController) {
        let cell = unrelated.unrelatedCustomCell() as! Cell<Self>
        cell.bind(self as! Self, viewController: viewController)
    }
}

class Cell<ViewModel:CellViewModel>: unrelated {
    func bind(_ vm: ViewModel, viewController: ViewController) {
        viewController.textView.text = "in base Cell class"
    }
}

// a custom implementation of the CellViewModel and Cell classes.
class CustomCellViewModel: CellViewModel {}
class CustomCell:Cell<CustomCellViewModel> {
    override func bind(_ vm: CustomCellViewModel, viewController: ViewController) {
        viewController.textView.text = "in child CustomCell class"
    }
}
```

When I run this code in **debug**, the textViews text is set to: "in child CustomCell class"
But, when I run the same code in **production**, the textViews text is set to: "in base Cell class"

Why does this differ between production and debug?

- I thought that this may have been related to this other question: [how to cast up to super class when there is an override function in the sub class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43138320/how-to-cast-up-to-super-class-when-there-is-an-override-function-in-the-sub-clas), but if that's the case, why does it only show up in production and not in debug?
- I've already tried disabling compiler optimizations in the build settings.
- I also thought this may be related to https://forums.swift.org/t/default-protocol-implementation-inheritance-behaviour-the-current-situation-and-what-if-anything-should-be-done-about-it/28049/10, but can't tell for certain.
- It's also worth noting that if you take out all of the generics in the `Cell` class, the issue goes away in production.